# Update a Pyspark DF Column based on an Array in another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my pyspark dataframe schema:

```
root
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
 |-- table: string (nullable = true)
 |-- changeDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fieldList: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- value: double (nullable = false)
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- temp: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- num_cols_changed: integer (nullable = true)
```

The data in the dataframe:

```
+--------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+------+------+-----+----+--------------------+----------------+
|    user|table|          changeDate|           fieldList|     id|value2|value|name|                temp|num_cols_changed|
+--------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+------+------+-----+----+--------------------+----------------+
| user11 | TAB1| 2016-01-24 19:10...|         value2 = 100|555555|   200|  0.5| old|      [value2 = 100]|               1|
| user01 | TAB1| 2015-12-31 13:12...|value = 0.34,name=new|  1111|   200|  0.5| old|[value = 0.34,  n...|               2|
+--------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+------+------+-----+----+--------------------+----------------+
```

I want to read the array in temp column and based on the values in that, I want to change the column in the dataframe. For example, first row has only one column being changed i.e. `value 2`, so I want to update the column `df.value2` with the new value 100. similarly, in the next row, 2 columns are changed, so I need to extract value and name with their values and update appropriate columns in the dataframe. So output should be like:

```
+--------+-----+--------------------+------+------+-----+----+
|    user|table|          changeDate|    id|value2|value|name|
+--------+-----+--------------------+------+------+-----+----+
| user11 | TAB1| 2016-01-24 19:10...|555555|   100|  0.5| old|
| user01 | TAB1| 2015-12-31 13:12...|  1111|   200| 0.34| new|
+--------+-----+--------------------+------+------+-----+----+
```

I want to keep the performance of the program in mind, hence focussing on ways just using dataframes, but if there is no options I can go rdd route too.
Basically, I do not know how to process multiple values in a row and then compare. I know that I can compare column names using `column in df.columns`, but doing this for each row using an array is confusing me. Any help or new idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I resolved this using `explode`:

```
df = df.withColumn('temp', split(df.fieldList, ','))
df = df.withColumn('cols', explode(df.temp))
df = df.withColumn('col_value', split(df.cols, '='))
df = df.withColumn('deltaCol', df.col_value[0])
       .withColumn('deltaValue',df.col_value[1])
```

Final Output of the above (after dropping irrelevant columns) resulted in this:

```
+------+-----+--------+--------------------+--------+----------+
|    id|table|    user|          changeDate|deltaCol|deltaValue|
+------+-----+--------+--------------------+--------+----------+
|555555| TAB2| user11 | 2016-01-24 19:10...| value2 |       100|
|  1111| TAB1| user01 | 2015-12-31 13:12...|  value |      0.34|
|  1111| TAB1| user01 | 2015-12-31 13:12...|   name | 'newName'|
+------+-----+--------+--------------------+--------+----------+
```

After this I registered it as a table and performed SQL operation to pivot the data:

```
>>> res = sqlContext.sql("select id, table, user, changeDate, max(value2) as value2, max(value) as value, max(name) as name \
... from (select id, table, user, changeDate, case when trim(deltaCol) == 'value2' then deltaValue else Null end value2,\
... case when trim(deltaCol) == 'value' then deltaValue else Null end value,\
... case when trim(deltaCol) == 'name' then deltaValue else Null end name from delta) t group by id, table, user, changeDate")
```

The result of this was:

```
+------+-----+--------+--------------------+------+-----+----------+
|    id|table|    user|          changeDate|value2|value|      name|
+------+-----+--------+--------------------+------+-----+----------+
|555555| TAB2| user11 | 2016-01-24 19:10...|   100| null|      null|
|  1111| TAB1| user01 | 2015-12-31 13:12...|  null| 0.34| 'newName'|
+------+-----+--------+--------------------+------+-----+----------+
```

For usage of this code with different tables, I used the columns of the master DF(my eventual target table) to prepare a string of columns:

```
>>> string = [(", max(" + c + ") as " + c) for c in masterDF.columns]
>>> string = "".join(string)
>>> string
', max(id) as id, max(value) as value, max(name) as name, max(value2) as value2'
```